# ffmpeg-python crossfade transition for unknown number of videos

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, transition

How to pass a list of file names (videos) to ffmpeg and have it concat and crossfade between each in the simplest way?

Thanks

Comment: Compose the complex filter graph in python and call ffmpeg with all video files as separated inputs

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.